# Custom permission through UI

Tags: permissions

Is there any extension that allow user to create permission through UI so that they can be used for defining permission for menu items or reports or form(eg form builder extension)

Comment: sounds like you sorted this. presumably you will add an answer when you get the extension published  - well done :-)

Comment: Not sure if i can publish this extension under https://civicrm.org/extensions without authority from core.

Comment: try pasting this in the ~extensions room: @bgm could you create a new extension repo on lan.civicrm.org/extensions? Called custompermissions (or something similar)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pushed [Custom permission](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/custompermissions/) extension, where you can create your own permission through UI by navigating to CiviCRM >> Administrator >> Customize Data and Screens >> Custom Permissions